# Visual Studio 2022; c++; NuGet Or-Tools Problem: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, nuget, or-tools

I'm trying to learn how to use Or-Tools with c++ to solve some problems.  I have created a VS2022 project by copying the LinearProgrammingExample.cpp from the Google Or-Tools website [text](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/lp_example) and installed the Google.OrTools.runtime.win-x64 NuGet package [text](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.OrTools.runtime.win-x64/).

Building the debug I get the following results:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>simple_mip_program.cpp
1>C:\or-tools\ortools\linear_solver\linear_solver.h(305): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>C:\or-tools\ortools\linear_solver\linear_solver.h(375): warning C4267: 'return': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class absl::Duration & __cdecl absl::Duration::operator-=(class absl::Duration)" (??ZDuration@absl@@QEAAAEAV01@V01@@Z) referenced in function "class absl::Duration __cdecl absl::operator-(class absl::Duration,class absl::Duration)" (??Gabsl@@YA?AVDuration@0@V10@0@Z)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__int64 __cdecl absl::ToInt64Milliseconds(class absl::Duration)" (?ToInt64Milliseconds@absl@@YA_JVDuration@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: __int64 __cdecl operations_research::MPSolver::wall_time(void)const " (?wall_time@MPSolver@operations_research@@QEBA_JXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class absl::Time __cdecl absl::Now(void)" (?Now@absl@@YA?AVTime@1@XZ) referenced in function "public: class absl::Duration __cdecl operations_research::MPSolver::DurationSinceConstruction(void)const " (?DurationSinceConstruction@MPSolver@operations_research@@QEBA?AVDuration@absl@@XZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const *,int)" (??0LogMessage@google@@QEAA@PEBDH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl google::LogMessage::LogMessage(char const *,int,int)" (??0LogMessage@google@@QEAA@PEBDHH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl google::LogMessage::~LogMessage(void)" (??1LogMessage@google@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl google::LogMessage::stream(void)" (?stream@LogMessage@google@@QEAAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl google::LogMessageFatal::LogMessageFatal(char const *,int)" (??0LogMessageFatal@google@@QEAA@PEBDH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal(void)" (??1LogMessageFatal@google@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class operations_research::MPSolver * __cdecl operations_research::MPSolver::CreateSolver(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?CreateSolver@MPSolver@operations_research@@SAPEAV12@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class operations_research::MPVariable * __cdecl operations_research::MPSolver::MakeIntVar(double,double,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?MakeIntVar@MPSolver@operations_research@@QEAAPEAVMPVariable@2@NNAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class operations_research::MPConstraint * __cdecl operations_research::MPSolver::MakeRowConstraint(double,double,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?MakeRowConstraint@MPSolver@operations_research@@QEAAPEAVMPConstraint@2@NNAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: enum operations_research::MPSolver::ResultStatus __cdecl operations_research::MPSolver::Solve(void)" (?Solve@MPSolver@operations_research@@QEAA?AW4ResultStatus@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __int64 __cdecl operations_research::MPSolver::iterations(void)const " (?iterations@MPSolver@operations_research@@QEBA_JXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __int64 __cdecl operations_research::MPSolver::nodes(void)const " (?nodes@MPSolver@operations_research@@QEBA_JXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl operations_research::MPObjective::SetCoefficient(class operations_research::MPVariable const * const,double)" (?SetCoefficient@MPObjective@operations_research@@QEAAXQEBVMPVariable@2@N@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl operations_research::MPObjective::SetOptimizationDirection(bool)" (?SetOptimizationDirection@MPObjective@operations_research@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl operations_research::MPObjective::SetMaximization(void)" (?SetMaximization@MPObjective@operations_research@@QEAAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: double __cdecl operations_research::MPObjective::Value(void)const " (?Value@MPObjective@operations_research@@QEBANXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: double __cdecl operations_research::MPVariable::solution_value(void)const " (?solution_value@MPVariable@operations_research@@QEBANXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>simple_mip_program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl operations_research::MPConstraint::SetCoefficient(class operations_research::MPVariable const * const,double)" (?SetCoefficient@MPConstraint@operations_research@@QEAAXQEBVMPVariable@2@N@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl operations_research::SimpleMipProgram(void)" (?SimpleMipProgram@operations_research@@YAXXZ)
1>C:\test\or-tools\test\x64\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 20 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 6:48 PM and took 09.493 seconds ==========
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to link still

Comment: ".NET native wrapper for the Operations Research Tools project" doesn't seem to be a right dll for C++.

Comment: The proper source https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/cpp/binary_windows?hl=en